# Why is the empty constructor necessary?

Tags: c++

I have the following two classes:

```
class Image
{
public:
    Image(int size) { _size = size; };
    ~Image();

private:
    int _size;
};


class Renderer
{
public:
    Renderer(int size = 10) { _image = {size}; };
    ~Renderer();
private:
    Image _image;

};
```

On compilation I get: "no appropriate default constructor available".
If I add `Image();` the error message goes away.

So my question is, why is the empty constructor necessary? Under which circumstances will it get called?

Comment: Make the constructor of the Renderer class as, Renderer(int size = 10) : _image(Image(size)) {}.. Otherwise, it first tries to create an instance of _image, then you initialize it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because in the constructor of `Renderer` the `Image` member must first be constructed, before your constructor body is entered. In your `Renderer` constructor body you *assign* to the member, you don't *construct* it.

If you do it like this, the error disappears without having to provide a default constructor for `Image`:

```
Renderer(int size=10): _image(size) { }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a member in the Rendered class "Image _image"...it is not being passed any parameters while being created. To deal with this kind of parameter-less object creation a default constructor is required